# Number of independent columns of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with the concept of rank, and I was told to the number of linearly independent columns of Matrix $A$, where $A = xy^T, x,y$ both vectors. So I know that if I can find the number of linearly independent columns of A, I can tell its rank. But since $A$ is just a matrix equal to $xy^T$, how could I know the elements of $A$, and thus find the number of linearly independent columns of $A$?

Can I please inquire what $A = xy^T$ really tells me about?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Consider [using $\LaTeX$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format math. In this case it's as simple as putting \$\$ around each expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you write out the vectors as $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)$ and $y = (y_1 \ldots, y_n)$, then the matrix is just
$$ xy^T = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 y_1 & \ldots & x_1 y_n \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
x_m y_1 & \ldots & x_m y_n 
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Observe that every column is a multiple of the vector $x$.

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary vector $v$, $(xy^T)v=x(y^Tv)$, but this is just some scalar (in fact, $v\cdot y$) times $x$. The columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors, so every column of $xy^T$ is a scalar multiple of $x$, which means that the matrix has at most one linearly independent column.

An equivalent definition of rank is the dimension of the image of the transformation. In this case, every vector is mapped to a multiple of $x$, so the image is at most one-dimensional.

Comment: So if every column of xy^T is a scalar multiple of x, then why does it mean that the matrix A has only one linearly independent column? If the second column is a multiple of first column, and if the third column is a multiple of first column, then does it mean that the matrix has 2 linearly independent columns? Thank you

Comment: @Parker What’s your definition of linear independence?

Comment: I now get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Parker Glad I could help. Do you understand why I wrote *at most* one?

Comment: Is it because of zero vectors?

Comment: @Parker Close. The zero matrix has *no* independent columns.